# How does gradle know which subproject task to execute?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am playing with the example project at:
https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-in-action-source/tree/master/chapter06/listing_06_03-todo-project-dependencies

After I run the jettyRun task at the "web" subproject I got:

```
:model:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:model:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:model:classes UP-TO-DATE
:model:jar UP-TO-DATE
:repository:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:repository:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:repository:classes UP-TO-DATE
:repository:jar UP-TO-DATE
:web:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:web:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:web:classes UP-TO-DATE
:web:jettyRun
```

However in the gradle it only says "web" project depends on "repository" and "repository" depends on "model" which are project level dependencies. So when you run "jettyRun" how does gradle know which tasks to run in the subproject?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare that one project is dependent on another project this means that the first project is dependent on the **artifact** of the other project. In the java plug-in this artifact is produced by the [jar task](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11F93).